# Register custom file type with custom UI editor in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, mef

I found old article called **LearnVSXNow** and part [#30 - Custom Editors in Visual Studio](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/09/01/LearnVSXNowPart30.aspx). There is sample project **The Blog Item Editor** which shows how to make custom file type assigned with custom UI editor for this file type extension (.blit)
This sample uses project [VSXtra](http://vsxtra.codeplex.com/), which is written for **Visual Studio 2008**.

Can someone point me to some tutorial, how-to, or something how to do the same for **Visual Studio 2010** ? My goal is to register custom file type extension (e.g. *.myext1) within visual studio 2010, and assign my own custom UI designer (WinForms, derived from UserControl) to handle editing content of such file visually.

I found some samples, but each of that shows only changes on code text editor (highlight some words, etc). But i want to show my own toolwindow with my usercontrol within it.

PS: Part of creating custom toolwindow with my own usercontrol within it is not problem, i use [VSPackage Builder Project Template](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vspackagebuilder) to build and register it within visx. My problem is how to register custom file type to use this custom toolwindow to edit file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the core text editor changed significantly (nearly a total re-write, designed around MEF) in Visual Studio 2010, the general infrastructure for registering and supplying custom editors/designers did not change.

The ['Creating Custom Text Editors and Designers'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166329.aspx) page on MSDN is a good place to start. You should also be able to go through the VSPackage wizard and choose "Custom Editor" to get a basic editor in place. It will give you a simple RTF editor.

You can also check out these samples on the MSDN Code Gallery for more ideas and inspiration:

- [Editor with Toolbox Support](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EditorwithToolbox/)
- [Designer View Over XML Editor](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlwpfdesigner)

It is usually recommended that editors reside in a document window (as opposed to a tool window). This is the paradigm that nearly all the built-in editors/designers use in Visual Studio, and it's what users expect when opening something from Solution Explorer. Editing things in a ToolWindow can feel a bit unnatural.

My understanding is that VSXtra provides some additional helper/base classes (beyond what Microsoft supports) to make various tasks (like writing a custom editor/designer) simpler. It is by no means required to create a custom editor though.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, i will try links you provide!