# Use custom file extension for aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, intellisense

How can i handle an aspx page in a web application with custom extension?
Instead of test.aspx i want to use test.meExtension.
I want to preserve intellisence and all the other thinks an aspx page has

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263761/supporting-user-specified-file-extensions-in-custom-visual-studio-language-servi) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922861/register-custom-file-type-with-custom-ui-editor-in-visual-studio-2010) links

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpContext.RewriteUrl method` in order to modify your url

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx